# Random vector with fixed angle

Tags: statistics, uniform-distribution

I wish to draw uniformly a vector that has a given fixed angle to a predetermined vector. I am looking for a general formula for any space of dimensions $\geq2$ (because angles in a one-dimensional space does not make much sense).

In other words, given a fixed angle $\theta$ and an initial vector $u$, I wish to sample uniformly from the set

$$\{v\in\mathbb{R}^N| \arccos{\frac{u^Tv}{\|u\|\|v\|}}=\theta, \|v\|=1\}$$

Comment: If $N=2$ and $\theta=\pi/2$ then your set is a line. There is no uniform (ie translation invariant) distribution on $\mathbb R$. Do you want to fix or bound $\|v\|$?

Comment: you're right! I meant $\|v\|=1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $e_N$ be the $N^{\rm th}$ element of the standard basis of $\mathbb R^N$, and identify $\mathbb R^{N-1}$ with the subspace of $\mathbb R^N$ orthogonal to $e_N$. Let $S$ be the unit sphere in $\mathbb R^{N-1}$.

Let $T$ be any orthogonal transformation sending $e_N$ to $u/\|u\|$ (concretely you can find such a transformation using [Gram-Schmidt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process)). Then your set is exactly
$$
  T((\cos\theta)e_N+(\sin\theta)S).
$$
So it suffices to sample uniformly from $S$. One way is to sample from an $(N-1)$-dimensional Gaussian and normalize ([see this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/397116/)).

Answer (score 0):

There's a two-step simple method. and I'll restate the problem so that it is slightly more general:

You have a vector $u$ of arbitrary size and you want to compute a vector $v$ with the same norm as $u$ but rotated by an angle $\theta$

1. find $w$, a random orthogonal vector to $u$ (i.e. $w^Tu=0$) with the same norm as $u$
2. Compute $v = (\cos\theta) u + (\sin\theta) w$.

You can find $w$ easily in three steps

a. find random $p$ (e.g. by sampling from a Gaussian)

b. $w' = p - \frac{p^Tu}{u^Tu}u$

c. $w = \|u\|\frac{w'}{\|w'\|}$